# How to find the Roots of the Derivative of two summed Gaussians.

Tags: calculus, transcendental-equations

Let $G$ be the Gaussian
$$G(t,w,c,h)=w\cdot e^{-\dfrac{(t-c)^2}{2h^2}}$$
for some real parameter $t$ and the real constants $w$, $c$, and $h$. Now, let $F$ be a function defined in terms of $G$,
$$F(t,w,c,h,o)=G(t,w,c-o,h)-G(t,w,c+o,h)$$
where $o$ is an additional real constant. We then have that the derivative of $F$ with respect to $t$ is
$$F'(t)=\frac{w(t-c-o)\cdot e^{-\dfrac{(t-c-o)^2}{2h^2}} - w(t-c+o)\cdot e^{-\dfrac{(t-c+o)^2}{2h^2}}}{h^2}$$
I want to find the real roots of $F'(t)$. That is, I want to solve $F'(t)=0$ for $t$ where $t$ is real.

I've tried isolating $t$ by hand to no avail. I get stuck already at the initial step when I try to take the natural logarithm of the entire expression in an attempt to dissolve the exponential terms.

The function $F$ models the shape of a disturbance to an electrical signal in a small system that I'm working on. The roots of the derivatives are useful in my later analysis. Specifically, I can use the roots to pair the electrical disturbance with the type of event that provoked it.

Thus far I have been using numerical root finding but I thought that an analytical solution must be available. I've also tried to expand $F$ using both Taylor and Poisson series. Unfortunately, the series expansions quickly diverge from the actual signal for a reasonable number of terms.

Comment: You might want to improve your math formatting. Take a look [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for tips.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Even if you couldn't isolate t, you should have shown your work. You will find your questions being downvoted if you don't. It is also, usually, exptected that you provide some context for the problem. Is this a homework problem, something you made up while eating breakfast? Whatever.

Comment: @StevenGregory, thanks for the comments! I've added some additional details.

Comment: @wltrup, how can I specifically improve the math formatting? I'm new to MathJax.

Comment: @FrederikAalund I'd suggest using double-dollar-signs for complicated expressions and/or those that have complicated exponents. They render much better that way. I don't know how it looks on your browser but, on mine (Safari), the first and third expressions look mangled. The middle one is fine.

Comment: @wltrup Thanks for the suggestion. I've edited the question to use double dollar signs. It wasn't a problem in my browser (Chrome on Win10) so I couldn't see the issue myself.

Comment: Looks much better now, but still mangled. I've seen that before. I think it's a bug in MathJax. Don't worry too much about it. Just be aware that these quirks happen.

Comment: @FrederikAalund Your formatting looks much better now. You might want to see what happens when you use \dfrac instead of \frac. You may or may not like the results.

Comment: @StevenGregory Thanks again! I'm using \dfrac now and indeed the formatting is much better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't factor it because it is a trascendental equation. But you can simplify a bit, and then use numerical methods. You can rewrite the equation as

$$
(t-c-o)e^{-\dfrac{[(t-c)^2+o^2-2o(t-c)]}{2h^2}}-(t-c+o)e^{-\dfrac{[(t-c)^2+o^2+2o(t-c)]}{2h^2}}=0
$$

Then you can factor and cancel $e^{-\frac{(t-c)^2+o^2}{2h^2}}$ to get

$$
(t-c-o)e^{\dfrac{2o(t-c)}{2h^2}}-(t-c+o)e^{-\dfrac{2o(t-c)}{2h^2}}=0
$$

Using hyperbolic sine/cosine, this can be written as

$$
2(t-c)\cdot\sinh\left(\dfrac{o(t-c)}{h^2}\right)-2o\cdot \cosh\left(\dfrac{o(t-c)}{h^2}\right)=0.
$$

If you want, you can make it a little more compact by passing to the hyperbolic tangent:

$$
(t-c)\cdot\tanh\left(\dfrac{2o(t-c)}{2h^2}\right)=o.
$$

Once you get here, there's not much algebra can help you with. You are basically trying to solve $\tanh(x) = a/x$. The solutions to this equation (there are two) can only be computed approximately with numerical methods.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for introducing me to the notion of transcendental equations. I was unaware that there is a formally-defined category of equations which often do not have closed-form solution. Also, I appreciate the simplification of $F$ to a function of $tanh$. Cheers!